# Express: next(err) stacktrace

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I find it difficult to find where the error occured when using `next(err)`. Is there a way how to save the stack to trace the error back to the original files? (Even if it was a validation error I would like to know the exact place from where it originated.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add error.stack to your error handling.

```
console.log(error, error.stack)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack

Comment: Oh man, how true you are!!! I was expecting `console.log(error.stack)` to return the same error just like `console.log(error)`. But `error.stack` covers even the lines from my own code. Thx bro!